# Calling eclipse build from command line

Tags: eclipse, build

How to trigger a debug/release build from eclipse using command line? 
I do not need IDE UI functionality (it should not bring up UI) and it should generate makefiles on the fly and start the build from command line.

What I need is to call eclipse and trigger the build from command line. 
it is used to build c code.

Comment: Have you tried calling `make` from that directory?

Comment: Hello Eli, once the makefiles are generated, I can run 'make all' to run the build. But I want the makefiles also generated from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below command in top level makefile to achieve this (lpcxpressoc is eclipse based IDE from NXP)

```
lpcxpressoc -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild --launcher.suppressErrors -cleanBuild #{ABC_PROJECT}/Release -data #{ABC_BUILDDIR} -importAll #{ABC_DIR}
```

It generates the makefiles on the fly and runs the build.